# loop through radio button, function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, loops

Not sure why this function wont start. Checked it, read a lot on SO, nothing... 
I'm sure there is very small mistake somewhere, where i cant spot..

```
<form id="order">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                What type of pica would you like?<br>
                Vegetarian, £6.50 <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="vegetarian"><br>
                Meat Lover, £7.20 <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="meatLover"><br>
                Hawaian, £5.5 <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="hawaian">
                <br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

var picaPrice = new Array();
    picaPrice['vegetarian']=6.5;
    picaPrice['meatLover']=7.2;
    picaPrice['hawaian']=5.5;

    function calcul(){
        var pprice = 0;
        var selectedPica = document.getElementsByName('pica');
        for(var i=0; i<selectedPica.length; i++){
            if(selectedPica[i].checked) {
                alert('selected');
            }
            else { alert('not selected') }
        }

    }
```

Done. Thank you for your help

Comment: did you use the <script> tag ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) function returns an array of all DOM elements that their **tag name** is equal to the given parameter (such as `input`, `div`, etc.). If you want to select elements by their `name attribute`, you should use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) instead.

```
var selectedPica = document.getElementsByName('pica');
```

---

> ## document.getElementsByName
>
> Returns a list of elements with a given **name** in the (X)HTML document.
>
> ## document.getElementsByTagName
>
> Returns a HTMLCollection of elements with the given **tag name**. The
> complete document is searched, including the root node. The returned
> HTMLCollection is live, meaning that it updates itself automatically
> to stay in sync with the DOM tree without having to call
> document.getElementsByTagName again.

Comment: Thank a lot for this, i didnt knew that difference.

Comment: But still it doesnt work, is there somehing wrong with my loop?
(answer is not full, function still not working :) )

Comment: @NitishKumar, I just did. Don't let your aggression about the fact that your answer is bad practice out on me...

Comment: @NitishKumar I've started what? I've pointed out the fact that you're assuming there's only one form in the DOM and it is really bad programming practice. My code relies on the elements' name, just like the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

You script is almost fine, just use getElementsByName instead ...ByTagName as already mentioned.

```
var picaPrice = new Array();
picaPrice['vegetarian']=6.5;
picaPrice['meatLover']=7.2;
picaPrice['hawaian']=5.5;


function calcul(){
    var pprice = 0;
    var selectedPica = document.getElementsByName('pica');
    var res = document.getElementById('result').value;
    for(var i=0; i<selectedPica.length; i++){
        if(selectedPica[i].checked) {
            alert('selected');
        }
        else { alert('not selected') }
    }

}
```

In addition, your script references a result item. Your html markup doesn't provide this, just add a div with id="result"...

```
<form id="order">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            What type of pica would you like?<br>
            Vegetarian, £6.50 
            <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="vegetarian"><br>
            Meat Lover, £7.20 <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="meatLover"><br>
            Hawaian, £5.5 <input type="radio" name="pica" onclick="calcul();" value="hawaian">
            <br><br>
        </td>
                <td><div id="result"></div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: result is in code, this code is just fragment. But I cant seem to make my function work

Comment: Its just working fine, http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/mcEQa/
Of cause if your posted code is the full content of your html page, you have to put your javascript into a <script></script> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedPica = document.getElementsByTagName('pica');
```

[getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) works not like that.

example:

```
 <script>
    function getElements()
      {
      var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      alert(x.length);
      }
    </script>

    <input type="text" size="20"><br>
    <input type="text" size="20"><br>
    <input type="text" size="20"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many input elements?">
```

what u are looking is [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

```
function getElements()
{
var x=document.getElementsByName("x");
alert(x.length);
}
</script>
Cats:
<input name="x" type="radio" value="Cats">
Dogs:
<input name="x" type="radio" value="Dogs">

<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many elements named 'x'?">
```

Comment: Just a tip, it's not fashionable on SO to link to `w3schools`. You may want to link to better sites.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line var var selectedPica = document.getElementsByTagName('pica'); to selectedPica = document.getElementsByName('pica');

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="order" name="orderForm">
 var selectedPica = document.getElementsByTagName('pica');
```

Replace To:

```
var selectedPica = document.forms['orderForm'].elements['pica'];
```

See [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8hg61R4o5KiCabGdbKl?p=preview)